# mongoose population ignores options

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having trouble understanding the population logic of mongoose.

I have a UserSchema which holds an array of articles.

```
articles: {
    type: [{
        article: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Article"
        },
        read: Boolean,
        starred: Boolean
    }]
},
```

Articles are stored in a separate collection. Now I want to find all starred articles of a user, populate these articles, sort them by published date and paginate the result.

```
User.findOne({_id: user.id, "articles.starred": true}).populate({path: "articles.article", options: {sort: {"published": -1}, skip: 20, limit: 20}}).exec(function(err, _user) {
    callback(_user);
});
```

The problem is, that the population is done, but the options are completely ignored.

Here is how a user and an article looks like:

**User:**

```
{
    "__v" : 0,
    "_id" : ObjectId("5284ef45fe46a55194000003"),
    "articles" : [ 
        {
            "article" : ObjectId("5284ef52fe46a55194000005"),
            "read" : true,
            "starred" : true,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5284ef53fe46a55194000ae1")
        }
    ],
    "categories" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5284ef52fe46a55194000004"),
            "feeds" : [ 
                {
                    "url" : "http://feeds.dzone.com/zones/dotnet",
                    "name" : ".NET Zone - Community for .NET developers everywhere"
                }
            ],
            "name" : ".NET"
        }
    ],
    "email" : "xxxx",
    "google" : {},
    "name" : "xxxx",
    "provider" : "xxxx"
}
```

**Article:**

```
{
    "author" : "Michael Hession",
    "title" : "You'll Never Want to Put Away This Elegant Pour-Over Coffee Dripper",
    "published" : ISODate("2013-06-13T16:38:00.000Z"),
    "link" : "http://gizmodo.com/youll-never-want-to-put-away-this-elegant-pour-over-co-513136433",
    "feed" : {
        "title" : "Gizmodo",
        "link" : {
            "html" : "http://gizmodo.com",
            "xml" : "feed/http://feeds.gawker.com/gizmodo/excerpts.xml"
        }
    },
    "summary" : "html content",
    "_id" : ObjectId("5284ef52fe46a55194000005"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include some sample user and article docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I couldn't find a solution yet, I made a workaround.

```
User.findOne({_id: user.id, "articles.starred": false}).populate({path: "articles.article"}).exec(function(err, _user) {
    if (!err && _user) {
        var articles = _user.articles.sort(function(art1, art2) {
            d1 = art1.article.published;
            d2 = art2.article.published;

            if (d1 > d2) return -1;
            if (d1 < d2) return 1;

            return 0;
        }).slice(skip, skip + 20);

        callback(articles);
    } else {
        callback([]);
    };
});
```

If someone comes up with a better idea, please let me know.

## Update:

After a lot of research I changed my UserSchema and found a better solution, that uses population like it is explained in the mongoose API docs.

### UserSchema:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: ""
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        default: ""
    },
    provider: {
        type: String,
        default: ""
    },
    categories: {
        type: [Category]
    },
    articles: {
        read: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Article"}],
        unread: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Article"}],
        starred: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Article"}]
    },
    google: {},
    facebook: {},
    twitter: {}
});
```

### getFeed:

```
User.findById(user.id, "articles." + params.state, function(err, _user) {
    User.populate(_user, {path: "articles." + params.state, options: {sort: {"published": -1}, skip: params.skip, limit: 20}}, function(_err, __user) {
        if (!_err && __user) {
            callback(__user.articles[params.state]);
        } else {
            callback([]);
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for updating this. I also have this problem where `options` does not seem to have any effect. I see alot of changes from the example in your question to you final solution. Among them changed Schema and changed from using promise to callback in query,  Do you know exactly what was the problem with the example in your question?